# Import Error for SparkSession in Pyspark

Tags: python

I have version 2.0 of Spark installed. I am using Pyspark, on Python 2.7. I seem to have no difficulties creating a SparkContext, but for some reason I am unable to import the SparkSession. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: cannot import name SparkSession
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough this worked perfectly from a different directory. Running the files from this path did not result in an error!

/Users/.../spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/

Answer (score 0):

SparkSession was introduced in Apache Spark 2. 
To use it, you should specify the right version of spark before running pyspark:

```
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
```

Answer (score 0):

export the correct spark version of spark installed by you, it worked for me for my version 2.3

export SPARK_VERSION=2.3

Comment: The version OP is using appears to be 2.1 (from his own answer). Can you also include an explanation of what is happening and why this flag needs to be set?

Comment: When you are running spark code from machine where spark configs are scattered in different paths, we need to export it's version in our code.